On premise Power BI: 404 - File or directory not found
We have an on premise PowerBI server, which can be reached internally. But, when we created an URL for outside client. We got an error 404 - File or directory not found.
Any idea about this error?
enter image description here
We've tried IIS binding and added Inbound rules for the port. Still getting the error when browsing the report.
